# replacing values in a df based on the values in another df if a coincidence exists in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df1:

```
 Id   value
'so'   5
'fe'   6
'd1'   4
```

Then I have a ref_df:

```
 Id    value
'so'    3
'fe'    3
'ju'    2
'd1'    1
```

I want to check that if any of the Ids in ref_df appear in df1, then replace the value in df1 by the ref_df.

The desired output would be:

```
 Id   value
'so'   3
'fe'   3
'd1'   1
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @jezrael I think it is not really a duplicate given that the dfs have diferent columns

Comment: hmmm, why do you think so?

Comment: @jezrael: because here a column is replaced with values in another dataframe that acts as some sort of dictionary. It is not joining two columns together. Joining can help here, although there exists a more simple solution, like `df1['Id'].replace(df2.set_index('Id')['value'])`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - You are right, dupe is changed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
df1['Value'] = df1['Id'].map(ref_df.set_index('Id')['Value'])
```

O/P:

```
   Id  Value
0  so      3
1  fe      3
2  dl      1
```